# How to link Android Studio and NDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have Android Studio. I have downloaded the NDK package and extracted all the files. What do I do next? How do I link NDK with Android Studio? I am an amateur, so detailed explanation would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: check in your module settings and add ndk path there.

Comment: Where exactly in my module settings do I add the ndk path?

Comment: well there is a jdk location,sdk location and ndk location

Comment: Mine has only SDK location and Jdk location. Do I need an updated version or something?

Comment: update your studio to 1.3

Comment: Thanks. I will do that and get back in case I am still stuck.

Comment: sure.If it helps i'll put it as an answer for u to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your NDK path in your module settings of the project.
Then you need to go to **SDK Location** where you'll find three options

1>Sdk Location

2>Jdk Location

3>Ndk Location

You can add your ndk path to Ndk location.For example see [image: THIS]

*note:- you'll need android-studio 1.3 or higher for this.